# Wordpress: Show action only for administrator and author roles

Tags: wordpress

How can show this code for all administrator roles and author roles in my site.

This code is custom to show all user post in budypress

**Edit:-**

```
$theuser = bp_displayed_user_id(); 
$user = new WP_User( $theuser );
$theuserrole = $user->roles[0];

if ($theuserrole == "author" || $theuserrole == "administrator")

{
    add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'add_profileposts_tab', 100 );
    function add_profileposts_tab() {

    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item( array(

    'name' => 'programs',

    'slug' => 'programs',

    'screen_function' => 'bp_postsonprofile',

    'default_subnav_slug' => 'programs', 

    'position' => 25
    )
    );
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Variant 1

```
<?php 
function answer_27680528($query) {
    global $user_level;

        if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 1) {
            // you code here
        }
        unset($user_level);

        return $query;
    }
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'answer_27680528');
?>
```

### User Level to Role Conversion

- User Level 0 converts to Subscriber
- User Level 1 converts to Contributor
- User Level 2 converts to Author
- User Level 3 converts to Editor
- User Level 4 converts to Editor
- User Level 5 converts to Editor
- User Level 6 converts to Editor
- User Level 7 converts to Editor
- User Level 8 converts to Administrator
- User Level 9 converts to Administrator
- User Level 10 converts to Administrator

## Variant 2

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
    // stuff here for admins or editors
<?php } ?>
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131816

Comment: You need to explain a bit more past the link.

Comment: Not for current user. I need for the budypress user